# How can I export to PDF with SketchUp API?

Tags: c++, ruby, api, sketchup

I need to export a model from the SketchUp Pro API (Ruby or C++) to PDF. There is a native PDF exporter in SketchUp, but it looks like there is no way to access it with the SketchUp API. Maybe I'm missing something... Can I export via API to PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any methods referring to PDFs, and this is from the documentation to [Model.export](https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/model#export):

> The `export` method is used to export a given file format. It knows which format to export based on the file extension you place on the file name... For SketchUp Pro 7.1+, valid extensions include `dae`, `kmz`, `3ds`, `dwg`, `dxf`, `fbx`, `obj`, `wrl`, and `xsi`. SketchUp Free only supports `dae` and `kmz`.

This doesn't conclusively prove that it's not possible, but it sure makes it look unlikely.  I guess your best bet is finding a way to convert from one of the supported formats to PDF.

Comment: maybe with cpp or external tool ?